# Error importing requests module "cannot import idna from encodings"

Tags: python-2.7, ironpython

I am trying to import the requests module. I manually put the necessary module files into my lib folder and I am getting this message in return. All I am running is "import requests"

Message: cannot import idna from encodings

Traceback:

line 16, in , "C:\Users\Thomas.Chu\AppData\Roaming\McNeel\Rhinoceros\7.0\Plug-ins\IronPython (814d908a-e25c-493d-97e9-ee3861957f49)\settings\lib\requests\models.py"

line 135, in , "C:\Users\Thomas.Chu\AppData\Roaming\McNeel\Rhinoceros\7.0\Plug-ins\IronPython (814d908a-e25c-493d-97e9-ee3861957f49)\settings\lib\requests_*init*_.py"

line 1, in , "C:\Users\Thomas.Chu\AppData\Local\Temp\TempScript.py"

I am trying to use the requests model in rhino python editor, which uses IronPython 2.7 I believe.